# Proper way of eliminating letter repetitions from English words?

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis, linguistics

As the title clearly describes, I wonder what is the right way to eliminate character repetitions in English that are commonly used in social media to exaggerate the feeling. Since I am developing a software solution to correct mistyped words, I need a global algorithm that can be applied to most majority of English words. So, I am asking experts to learn the right way to eliminate additional letters in English words without using learning-based approachs?

ps. (1) I check programmatically if the word is valid or not using the [WordNet 3.0 database](https://wordnet.princeton.edu). So far so good except some examples such as the word `veery` which is defined as `tawny brown North American trush noted for its song` in WordNet 3.0. I interrupt letter elimination process when the word is found in WordNet. So are there any other knowledge bases that can be used instead of WordNet?

ps. (2) Actually I asked this question at [English Language & Usage community](http://english.stackexchange.com). But they guided me to ask it here.

**Some examples:**

```
haappyy --> happy
amaaazzinng --> amazing
veeerry --> very
```

As you see in the examples, the place of letter repetition various through the word.

Comment: Can you not link to your question on [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/)?-- it would be nice to see what people have to say on there in order to better formulate a comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 5):

One major problem in mapping a non-canonical form with [reduplicated letters](http://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2013/03/dragging-it-out/309220/) to its canonical form is that it is ambiguous without context: Consider e.g. *meeet* — is that actually *met* or *meet*?

One way of addressing this could be to measure a word's "canonicity" as the probability of it given its context (i.e. the words preceding it) in an *n*-gram model: Words which are judged to be "aliases" of the word in question (described below) and are most frequent given the context at hand are treated as the "canonical" form:

### Normalization

It is possible to think of forms such as *veeerry* and *very* as variants of the same form, namely a modified "ordered bag of characters", so that e.g. both are processed as sequences of `('v','e','r','y')` albeit having different weighting:

- *veeerry*: `(('v', 1), ('e', 3), ('r', 2), ('y', 1))`
- *very*: `(('v', 1), ('e', 1), ('r', 1), ('y', 1))`

In this way, these forms can be processed like normal feature vectors — this will be used to weight their probabilities below.

### Aliasing

We need to be able to map e.g. *veeerry* to *very* without, as you described, matching to the uncommon word [*veery*](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=veery&sub=Search+WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=). Therefore, simply representing *veeerry* as an "ordered bag of characters" without any weighting would mean that *veeerry* would just as plausibly be a variant of [*veery*](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=veery&sub=Search+WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=) — which it obviously isn't. However, since [*veery*](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=veery&sub=Search+WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=) most likely has a very different [lexical distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributional_semantics) than to that of the adverb *very*, it would be possible to get the sense of a normalized `('v','e','r','y')` based on its probability given its context — for example:

1. *This car is veery big.*
2. <sup>#</sup>*This car is a veery.* ("This car is a tawny brown North American thrush noted for its song")

Even without considering the syntactic [part-of-speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part_of_speech) distinction between these two examples (the first is an adverb and the second one is a noun), the raw statistical distribution of these two different words is very different. For that reason, given a good model, `P(veery_1 | "This car is") > P(veery_2 | "This car is a")`.

#### Probabilistic weighting

In order to associate e.g. *veeerry* to *very* in order to normalize it when found in a text while still keeping [*veery*](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=veery&sub=Search+WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=) from being normalized to *very*, we can then simply use the feature vector for the ordered bag of characters representing *veeerry* to calculate its distance from both *very* and [*veery*](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=veery&sub=Search+WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=) and then use that distance to weight the probability of each in the given context:

```
best_term(form, context) = argmax(arg=term, (P(term, context) * sim(ordered_bag_of_chars(form), ordered_bag_of_chars(term)))
```

I've written a bit of Python code in order to better explain how this might work in real life:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

class Vocabulary(object):
    def __init__(self, forms):
        self.forms = forms
        self.form_variations = {}   
        for form in forms:
            unique_symbol_freqs = tuple(count_unique_symbol_freqs(form))
            unique_symbols = tuple(unique_symbol_freq[0] for unique_symbol_freq in unique_symbol_freqs)
            self.form_variations[unique_symbols] = WeightedSymbolSequence(unique_symbol_freqs)

class WeightedSymbolSequence(object):
    def __init__(self, unique_symbols):
        # TODO: Finish implementation
        pass

def count_unique_symbol_freqs(input_seq):
    if len(input_seq) > 0:
        # First process the head symbol
        previous_unique_symbol = (input_seq[0], 1)
        # Process tail symbols; Add extra iteration at the end in order to handle trailing single unique symbols
        tail_iter = iter(input_seq[1:])
        try:
            while True:
                input_symbol = next(tail_iter)
                if input_symbol == previous_unique_symbol[0]:
                    previous_unique_symbol = (previous_unique_symbol[0], previous_unique_symbol[1] + 1)
                else:
                    result_unique_symbol = previous_unique_symbol
                    previous_unique_symbol =  (input_symbol, 1)
                    yield result_unique_symbol
        except StopIteration:
            # The end of the sequence was encountered; Handle a potential last unique symbol
            yield previous_unique_symbol

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sys import stderr

    tests = {"haappyy" : "happy", "amaaazzinng" : "amazing", "veeerry" : "very"}

    with open("/usr/share/dict/words", "r") as vocab_instream:
        # TODO: Alias uppercase versions of characters to their lowercase ones so that e.g. "dog" and "Dog" are highly similar but not identical
        vocab = Vocabulary(frozenset(line.strip().lower() for line in vocab_instream))

    for form1, form2 in tests.items():
        # First check if the token is an extant word 
        if form1 in vocab.forms:
            print("\"%s\" found in vocabulary list; No need to look for similar words." % form1)
        else:
            form1_unique_char_freqs = tuple(count_unique_symbol_freqs(form1))
            print(form1_unique_char_freqs)
            form2_unique_char_freqs = tuple(count_unique_symbol_freqs(form2))
            dist = cosine([form1_unique_char_freq[1] for form1_unique_char_freq in form1_unique_char_freqs], [form2_unique_char_freq[1] for form2_unique_char_freq in form2_unique_char_freqs])
            # TODO: Get probabilities of form variations using WeightedSymbolSequence objects in "vocab.form_variations" and then multiply the probability of each by the cosine similarity of bag of characters for form1 and form2

            try:
                # Get mapping to other variants, e.g. "haappyy" -> "happy"
                form1_unique_chars = tuple(form1_unique_char_freq[0] for form1_unique_char_freq in form1_unique_char_freqs)
                variations = vocab.form_variations[form1_unique_chars]
            except KeyError:
                # TODO: Use e.g. Levenshtein distance in order to find the next-most similar word: No other variations were found
                print("No variations of \"%s\" found." % form1, file=stderr)
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to trying to correct words entered by a user is to generate the possibilities ahead of time and store them. If you took a list of common words (no odd birds), created some rules for repeating vowels and then added all of them to your dictionary (e.g. an in-memory ternary tree) this could work.

The repeated 'e' form of 'very' would be stored as 'veery', 'veeery', ... and if you augmented Wordnet with frequency information, 'veery' as a misspelling of 'very' would be marked as being more common than 'veery' the bird.

I do something similar to this in my Natural Language engine where I'm also trying to handle another common social media aberration: the lack of spaces between words.

Comment: Exactly, normalizing concatenated words is another issue that needs to be handled. Between, how can I limit the list of common words? It would be a very subjective task.